# How to Code Hours, Minutes, Seconds Timer Visual Basic

Tags: timer

I'm trying to code a timer that counts up by 1 second the moment the form is loaded in Visual Basic.  I set Timer enabled to true and interval to 1000.  My timer counts up to 1 second and then stops.  I want it to keep working as long as the form is open.  I have three separate labels to display hours, minutes, and seconds, respectively.  What is the issue?

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Dim intSecond As Integer = 0
        Dim intMinute As Integer = 0
        Dim intHour As Integer = 0

        ' Declare timer variables. 

        intSecond = intSecond + 1
        ' Add one second to the timer per tick.

        lblSecond.Text = Format(intSecond, "00")
        lblMinute.Text = Format(intMinute, "00")
        lblHour.Text = Format(intHour, "00")

        If intSecond = 60 Then
            intMinute = intMinute + 1
            intSecond = 0
        End If
        ' Increase timer by 1 minute each time 60 seconds have passed.
        If intMinute = 60 Then
            intHour = intHour + 1
            intMinute = 0
        End If
        ' Increase timer by 1 hour each time 60 minutes have passed.
    End Sub
```

Comment: Visual Basic isn't my strong suite to say the least so can't quote the exact code in an answer, but it looks like all your variables are local inside the function and are set to 0 (and count back up to 1) every time the function runs. If you want the variables to keep their value, either declare them static or move the declaration outside the function.

Comment: Hello, Joachim.  Your comment was exactly right.  I declared the variables outside of the function and my timer works perfectly now.  Thank you so much!